# I don;t understand what is wrong with this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im getting a syntax error for elif option ==2:. I was wondering what I need to do to fix it. I followed the pseudocode my professor gave us but it still won't run. I'm wondering if I shouldn't have used elif or maybe something about the indentation is off.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the guess my number program")

while True:
        print("1. You guess the number")
        print("2. You type a number and see if the computer can guess it")
        print("3. Exit")
        option = int(input("Please enter your number here: "))
        if option ==1:
        #generates a random number
                mynumber = random.randint(1,11)
        #number of guesses
        count = 1
        while True:
                try:
                        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:"))
                        while guess < 1 or guess > 10:
                                guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:"))  # THIS LINE HERE
                except:
                        print("Numbers Only")
                        continue
                #prints if the number you chose is too low and adds 1 to the counter
                if guess < mynumber:
                        print("The number you chose is too low")
                        count= count+1
                #prints if the number you chose is too high and adds 1 to the counter
                elif guess > mynumber:
                        print("The number you choose is too high")  
                        count = count+1
#If the number you chose is correct it will tell you that you guessed the number and how many attempts it took
                elif guess == mynumber:
                        print("You guessed it in " , count , "attempts")
                        break
        elif option == 2:
                number = int(input("Please Enter a Number: "))
                count = 1
                while True:
                        randomval = random.randint(1,11)
                        if (number < randomval):
                                print("Too high")
                        elif (number > randomval):
                                print("Too low")
                                count = count+1
                        elif (number==randomval):
                                print("The computer guessed it in" + count + "attempts. The number was" + randomval)
                                break
                else:
                        break
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You should describe in the question the complete error, where it occurs, what you don't understand about the error, and reduce the code to the smallest example which still gives the error. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: oh ok. Thank you. I will do that

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like the while loop between your first if and the elif statement your talking about could be the problem might have to turn the elif into an if?  Not at my computer to test it

Comment: Your indenting is broken. The `elif ==2` doesn't have a corresponding `if`. You have `if option ==1` up above it, but then you exit it at `count = 1`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simple. There is no continuity between `if option == 1` and `elif option == 2`, because of the in between while loop. What you have to do is remove the `el` part of `elif option == 2` and just write `if option == 2`.

I haven't tested the whole program myself. But at a glance, this should rectify the problem.

Please comment if otherwise.